# How to get the other fields of a ForeignKey in Django

Tags: python, django

I have two models as Author and Comment

One is Comment and it has a ForeinKey points to Author(BlogUser)

```
class Comment(models.Model):
body = models.TextField('body', max_length=500)
created_time = models.DateTimeField('create_time', default=now)
last_mod_time = models.DateTimeField('last_mod_time', default=now)
author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, verbose_name='author', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
article = models.ForeignKey(Article, verbose_name='article', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
parent_comment = models.ForeignKey('self', verbose_name="parent_comment", blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
is_approved = models.BooleanField('is_approved', default=True, blank=False, null=False)
is_enabled = models.BooleanField('is_enabled', default=True, blank=False, null=False)
is_deleted = models.BooleanField('is_deleted', default=True, blank=False, null=False)
```

Author Model

```
class BlogUser(AbstractUser):

qq_number = models.CharField('QQ', max_length=20, default='')
```

I am trying to get all the comments related to a specified Article and display the comments list by the format of usernames and comment bodys.

In the view I filter all the comments by the article id, but after serializing the filter queryset, it gives me only the Author's primary id, how could I get the other feilds of Author? Shall I write a function by myself or there is some easier way to do it?

The view:

```
def get_comment_list(request, article_id):
if request.GET:
    comment_list = models.Comment.objects.filter(article_id = article_id)
    data = serializers.serialize('json',comment_list)
    return HttpResponse(data, content_type="application/json") 
else:
    PermissionDenied('Not accept post')
```

Comment: If you're building a site based on serialized data you definitely shouldn't rely on Django's built-in serializers. Use Django REST Framework which is much more flexible and will do what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to iterate the `comment_list` and with the member operator to access the fields of `author`

eg: `comment_list[0].author.field_name`

NOTE: Field name could be any field name that has been decleared in AUTH_USER_MODEL table like first_name, last_name or username.

Answer (score 0):

By default, django serializer does not provide information from ForeignKey. I would also recommend using Django Rest Framework Serializer(Denial Roseman mentioned in the comments) if you have the scope of using it.

Still you can use the django serializer, but you will need to override the `json.Serializer`'s `end_object()` method. There you canget the values of the user object like following example:

```
from django.core.serializers.json import Serializer 

class CustomSerializer(Serializer):

    def end_object(self, obj):
        for field in self.selected_fields:
            if field in self._current.keys():
                continue
            else:
                try:
                    self._current[field] = getattr(obj.author, field)  # Fetching the data from ForeignKey
                except AttributeError:
                    pass
        super(CustomSerializer, self).end_object(obj)
# usage
data = CustomSerializer().serialize(
      Comment.objects.all(),
      fields = (
        'pk',
        # other fields in Comment Object
        'username'  # it belongs to Author Model
      )
```

Downside of this solution is that, if BlogUser has same field as Comment, then it will fetch the value of `Comment`.

### More Advanced Implementation:

```
class CustomSerializer(Serializer):
    def end_object(self, obj):
        for field in self.selected_fields:
            if field in self._current.keys():
                continue
            else:
                if field.find('__') > -1:
                    try:
                        fks = field.split('__')
                        curr_value = obj
                        while(len(fks)>0):
                            current_key = fks.pop(0)
                            curr_value = getattr(curr_value, current_key)
                        self._current[field] = curr_value
                    except AttributeError:
                        pass
        super(CustomSerializer, self).end_object(obj)
# usage
data = CustomSerializer().serialize(
          Comment.objects.all(),
          fields = (
            'pk',
            # other fields in Comment Object
            'author__username'  # it belongs to Author Model
          )
```

Comment: Finally I use python json model to build the list and visit all the author's feild by `comment_list[0].author.field_name`

Comment: Is it even accurate? I mean the first comment's author is not author of all comments

Comment: Acutally I visit all the element of comment_list by a for loop. The code I wirte is cited from another answer above.